# Group types by common base class in given assembly

Tags: c#, reflection

In a given assembly, I want to find all types that have a common base class, but without specifying the base class, for example:

```
A : Base, IInterface
B : Base, IInterface
C : Base, IInterface
X : Other, IInterface
Y : Other, IInterface
```

I have 2 groups, A,B,C (inheriting from Base) and X,Y (inheriting from Other). Base and Other are abstract and all implements a common interface.

The method signature could be something like:

```
public IEnumerable<IGrouping<Type, IEnumerable<Type>>> FindGroups(Assembly assembly, Type @interface)
{
}
```

How can I create those groups?

Comment: Enumerate all types to find groups, then enumerate all types again to group.

Comment: I dont completely follow your requirement. What would you pass in as param `@interface`? Is it `typeof(IInterface)`? And in which case what would you expect back in return using tthe example data?

Comment: yes, it is `typeof(IInterface)`. I expect a group where the key is the base type and the group items are the types that inherit from the base type (group key)

Comment: What would you do with types like `D : IInterface` or `E : A`?

Comment: @DavidG that's why I only care about types that inherit from an *abstract* class. The rest I don't care about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
public IEnumerable<IGrouping<Type, Type>> FindGroups(Assembly assembly, Type @interface)
{
    return assembly.GetTypes()
        .Where(t => @interface.IsAssignableFrom(t)
            && !t.IsAbstract
            && t.BaseType != null
            && t.BaseType.IsAbstract)
        .Select(t => new {baseType = t.BaseType, type = t})
        .GroupBy(x => x.baseType, x => x.type);
}
```

Comment: Whilst I wrote the first answer your´s is better.

Comment: Ack. Seeing as I was close to a very similar solution, Ill just leave the live example I was building here: http://rextester.com/JMVI51336

Comment: playing around with I found out another scenario: nested abstract classes. To fix, I've added a `Where(t=>t.type.IsAbstract == false)` before `GroupBy` clause.